# Database compatibility between QGIS and ArcMap

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, geopackage

I'm picking up ArcMap having started off in QGIS. I've been struggling for a while now to make databases that both QGIS 3.10 and ArcMap 10.7 can read and write. It seems ArcMap imposes much stricter conventions on data. I've run into the same problem with geopackages and now PostgreSQL. This isn't an exhaustive list of the headaches but as far as I can tell ArcGIS:

1. Only accepts lowercase letters, numbers and underscores in table names;
2. Will throw a SQL syntax error on loading if a table name starts with a number;
3. Only accepts lowercase letters, numbers and underscores in variable names - it'll show the geometry of layers that break this rule but throws an error when you try to view the attributes; and
4. Won't edit or display attributes for layers that include invalid geometries.

While I haven't tried naming a table or variable `#`, `@` or `"` in QGIS, it seems like anything goes. How can I open these databases in ArcMap?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You missed a bunch of other limitations actually imposed by ArcGIS clients, which make casual editing by both ArcGIS and QGIS nearly impossible. Most of the issues you've specified are part of the SQL language standard itself, or just plain best practice. Unfortunately, you have multiple questions here, which breaks the One question per Question policy, but since all the answers are No, I'm not sure it really matters.

Comment: As noted please only have 1 question, if you have more questions you can create other specific questions. as per guidelines https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So the answer is that, using QGIS, I've been violating the SQL language standard? Arc won't read that data, and no-one has a tool to go through table and variable names replacing forbidden characters with lowercase and underscores?

Comment: You've been allowed to utilize an extension to SQL naming rules specific to PostgreSQL, but ArcGIS doesn't use that extension, so invalid identifiers are invalid.